# Why is the numberOfRowsInComponent function ran so many times?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView in my controller class and it is show when user touches a button.

```
private var periodPicker = UIPickerView()
```

I have two components in it for years and months.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
     return 2
}
```

Now I though that the `numberOfRowsInComponent` function is ran only two times in the beginning -  one for one component and second for the other - and then it could be ran whenever a component is reloaded. I don't reload any of my two components, however when I insert a print in `numberOfRowsInComponent` function I get this output:

function:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return years.count
    } else {
        print("numberOfRowsInComponent")
        loadMonths()
        return months.count
    }
}
```

output:

```
numberOfRowsInComponent
numberOfRowsInComponent
numberOfRowsInComponent
<...>
numberOfRowsInComponent
numberOfRowsInComponent
```

My function is ran 19times! Is that normal behaviour from UIPickerView or not? Because it might impact my app's performance if it's not, right?

Comment: i think your this function `loadMonths()` contains `pickerview.reloadAllComponents()`

Comment: When your picker view has multiple components it needs to keep checking the number of rows as you change the selection; the number of rows in the second component could depend on the selection in the first (imagine months and days). This function should execute as quickly as possible. Why do you call `loadMonths` in this function?  Couldn't you do it once somewhere else?

Comment: I call `loadMonths` to update my months (second component data) based on my selected year (first component). However, I do not call `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` in `loadMonths`, nor do I call it in any other place.

Comment: I checked this out, and it will get called a bunch of times even if `numberOfRowsInComponent` returns a hard-coded number and selection never changes.  In my test project, it is called 14 times immediately.  (I was not able to determine why that particular number, just that it has nothing apparently to do with the number of rows in each of the components.)

Comment: @ChristopherThiebaut exactly, I forgot to tell that all these calls happen right away when I load the pickerview, not when I change selection or reload anything. Also, thank you for your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'd need an Apple employee who works on UIKit to tell you why. What I can tell you is that this appears to be normal.  I threw together a small sample project that does nothing interesting to investigate this and it seems a large number of calls to this function also happen in a small view controller with a picker view and nothing else.

I would say whether or not this impacts your app's performance depends on what you do with the fact that this is called a lot of times.  It doesn't really matter if it's normal behavior because you and I cannot fix it.  But, if you don't want it to impact performance, don't do heavy things in that function.

If `loadMonths` is heavy, maybe it's better to do elsewhere if you start having performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Christopher Thiebaut's answer since you were wondering if these extra calls would have a performance impact.

I am not sure why the method gets called 14 times, but I [don't think](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614381-numberofrowsincomponent?language=swift) it will have as bad a performance impact as you think if the data source doesn't change:

> A picker view fetches the value of this property from the data source
> and **caches** it. The default value is zero.